# Performance of Android adapters

Tags: android, performance, adapter

I have got a database. E. g., it contains two tables: Departments and Employees. There are a lot of items in both tables. The data will be populated to `ExpandableListView`. Now I use a custom adapter extending `CursorTreeAdapter`. The situation is good enough but sometimes it works slower than I'd like. Does the performance depend on a type of adapter? If so, which of the adapters is better?

**Code.**

```
private class MyAdapter extends CursorTreeAdapter implements OnClickListener {

    public MyAdapter(Cursor cursor, Context context) {
        super(cursor, context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    protected Cursor getChildrenCursor(Cursor groupCursor) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected View newGroupView(Context context, Cursor cursor, boolean isExpanded, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void bindGroupView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor, boolean isExpanded) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    protected View newChildView(Context context, Cursor cursor, boolean isLastChild, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void bindChildView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor, boolean isLastChild) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Comment: post your adapter and we might be able to help you better. more often than not performance issues with listviews have to do with doing more than needed or redundant code in the method that loads a view for each row or not utilizing the `convertView` mechanism correctly. in addition the `viewHolder` pattern has proven itself effective for listview performance as well.

Answer (score 3):

I think this might lead to part of your slowdown:

```
       Cursor indicatorsCursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(
                JsonDataProvider.Uris.IND_BY_BULLET_AND_COMPLEXITY, null, null,
                selectionArgs, null);
```

You shouldn't be pulling a cursor/running a query in a `getView` method... that is probably the cause of your slowdown since you are doing it for every view visible in the list, and then again for each view as you scroll.

If you must do it, do it smartly.  Don't pull the cursor until you have stopped scrolling.  Put a scroll listener in and a flag.  While scrolling, set the flag to true and enclose those data intensive bits of your adapter in an `if` statement that will skip them while the flag is set.  When you finish scrolling, clear the flag and use `notifyDataSetChanged` to force a redraw of the visible list items (which will now do the db query since you are not scrolling).

Set the listener on your listview:

```
listView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {   
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisible,   
    int visibleCount, int total) {   
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {   
            if (scrollState != 0)   
                listView.getAdapter().isScrolling = true;   
            else {   
                listView.getAdapter().isScrolling = false;  
                listView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();  
            }  
        }  
    });
```

And in your adapter surround the appropriate code with this:

```
if (!isScrolling) {
    // processor intensiver code here
}
```

Comment: thank you. I'll try it as well. Which class should implement `OnScrollListener` interface?

Comment: It would be attached to your listview.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: `if (!isScrolling) {
    // processor intensive code here
}`

@Barak, I didn't understand what I need to surround. I can't just surround the code from `getChildView` method, 'cause  not me but the system calls `getChildView`.

Comment: Not the whole thing, just the parts inside your `getChildView` method that are processor intensive... like the query (and any associated assignments to widgets from it, etc.)  Basically you want to cut out processing anything other than simple textviews from the existing childcursor while you are scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that you're actually using view recycling, the other option is to limit the amount of rows in your list. This could be done using a popular library called [**Pull to Refresh**](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh), so you could put 10-20 rows in a single page and then, when the user pulls, you can load 10-20 more, so the UI won't go slow.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the way you are binding your data to your view isn't optimized, i.e., you may have a 1000 row of data that you want to show in your listview you don't need to creating 1000 views to to show each row of your data, because the listview will only show the amount of view that can be seen in the screen, so android does a smart thing which is reuse the views that has been scrolled out of the screen, when you bind your data you should check if the view parameter passed to your method which is bind the data to view is null, if so create new one, if not reuse it.

For a better understanding watch this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70

Comment: That's what he's doing (the  if (convertView == null) part).

Comment: I'm gonna try using http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

Comment: @Shyish when I first read the question I didn't had any code listed! When a posted my answer I saw that I had just updated his question with code listing, and I was going out and I didn't read the code.